# (redis-om) TypeError: entity.toRedisJson is not a function

Tags: redis, electron

I'm try to use the Redis for my database and I would like to using redis-om for Electron, I'm not sure they are compatible or not, but I got error.

(node:7024) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: entity.toRedisJson is not a function

I don't know how can I fix and what I just messed?

// main.js
// first section without problem, I can save data to Redis

```
const { Entity, Schema, Client, Repository } = require('redis-om')
const client = new Client()
client.open('redis://localhost:6379')

class Album extends Entity {}
const albumSchema = new Schema(Album, {
  artist: { type: 'string' },
  title: { type: 'text' },
  year: { type: 'number' },
  genres: { type: 'string[]' },
  outOfPublication: { type: 'boolean' }
})

const albumRepository = client.fetchRepository(albumSchema);
const album = albumRepository.createEntity()
album.artist = 'Mushroomhead'
album.title = 'The Righteous & The Butterfly'
album.year = 2014
album.genres = [ 'metal' ]
album.outOfPublication = true
album = albumRepository.save(album)
```

// When I add following code try to change record and save it, I will got the error message.

```
album = albumRepository.fetch('01H2J234SXNXM34A3BZF60HW99');
album.title = ' test'
album = albumRepository.save(album)
```

I'm try to save data to Redis throung Redis-OM then update the existing data.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for my previous answer, I thought it was a version issue and didn't test it since I don't have version 0.3 installed.

After some tests in version 0.3 I think I found the issue: you have to await `save()` and `fetch()` function.

So instead of

```js
album.outOfPublication = true
album = albumRepository.save(album)
album = albumRepository.fetch('01H2J234SXNXM34A3BZF60HW99');
album.title = ' test'
album = albumRepository.save(album)
```

you should

```js
 
album.outOfPublication = true;
album = await albumRepository.save(album); // await here, this will return an entityId
album = await albumRepository.fetch(album); // await here, this will return an Entity object, without await you would get a pending Promise
album.title = "test";
album = albumRepository.save(album);
```

`fetch()` and `save()` are async as per [redis-om](https://github.com/redis/redis-om-node/blob/main/docs/classes/Repository.md#fetch) document.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)